# Azure AKS Persistent Volume and Storage class permissions

Tags: azure, permissions, aks

I am looking for specific permissions that will allow read access to view the storage configurations and set up in Azure AKS.

There just doesn't seem to be anyway to provide limited read access to these resources, I have tried most of the Storage and AKS reader roles and nothing seems to work. Applied at the resource level and subscription level and still no luck.